Study the uniqueness of the solution of the ODE $y' = \sqrt{y} , y(0) = 1$
$\frac{dy}{dx} = \sqrt{y}\\ \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}dy = \frac{1}{2}dx\\ \Rightarrow \int_{1}^{y}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{s}}ds = \int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{2}d\xi\\ \Rightarrow \sqrt{y} - 1 = \frac{1}{2}x\\ \Rightarrow \sqrt{y} = 1 + \frac{1}{2}x \\ \Rightarrow y = (1 + \frac{1}{2}x)^{2} , x \geq -2$.
How can I check the uniqueness of the solution?

We just need to apply Picard-Lindelof's theorem. Since $f(t,y)$ is continuous in $(t,y)$ in a neighborhood of $(0,1)$ and it is also Lipschitz with respect to $y$, we know that the initial value problem has a unique solution in that neighborhood. Additionally, solutions defined larger time intervals will coincide with solutions define for smaller time intervals.
